# Firebase as an OAuth Provider/Server?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

We use email/password firebase authentication. Say I have a third party vendor whose software we want to use but we do not want to manage separate user accounts. I know firebase can use OAuth Providers, but can it become an OAuth Provider?

Comment: This is not supported. You have to build that mechanism on top of Firebase Auth. I suggest you file a [feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/) for this.